# How to get current date and time from DB using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, database, date, time, sqlalchemy

I need to retrieve what's the **current date and time for the database I'm connected** with SQLAlchemy (not date and time of the machine where I'm running Python code). I've seen this functions, but they don't seem to do what they say:

```
>>> from sqlalchemy import *
>>> print func.current_date()
CURRENT_DATE
>>> print func.current_timestamp()
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Moreover it seems they don't need to be binded to any SQLAlchemy session or engine. It makes no sense...

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I foud the solution: these functions cannot be used in the way I used (`print...`), but need to be called inside of the code that interacts with the database. For instance:

```
print select([my_table, func.current_date()]).execute()
```

or assigned to a field in an insert operation.
Accidentally I discovered that exists at least a couple of parameters for these functions:

- `type_` that indicates the type of the value to return, I guess
- `bind` that indicates a binding to an SQLAlchemy engine

Two examples of use:

```
func.current_date(type_=types.Date, bind=engine1)
func.current_timestamp(type_=types.Time, bind=engine2)
```

Anyway my tests seems to say these parameters are not so important.